# How the time complexity of the following code is O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I was solving a time-complexity question on Interview Bit, which is given below in the image.
[image]

The correct answer to this question is O(N). But according to me, the answer should be O(NlogN). Since the complexity for the first "for loop" should be O(logN) because the variable i is divided by 2 in each iteration and I have studied that whenever the loop variables are either multiplied or divided by 2, then the time complexity is O(logN). Now, for the second "for loop", the complexity should be O(N), therefore, the final complexity should be O(N*logN).

Can anyone please explain where I am wrong?

Comment: Note that O(NlogN) is not actually _wrong_ since O() is an upper bound. It's just less informative than O(N).

Comment: Where you went wrong is that while the outer loop is entered O(log N) times, providing the idea that maybe the whole algorithm does take O(? * log N), the inner loop does not execute an average of cN times for some constant c, for each execution of the outer loop. As IVlad's answer states, you need to do the math leading to the geometric series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the actual math:

```
T(N) = N + N/2 + N/4 + ... + 1 (log_2 N terms in the sum)
```

This is a geometric series with ratio `1/2`, so the sum is equal to:

```
T(N) = N*[1 - (1/2)^(log_2 N)] / (1 - 1/2) =
     = [N - N/(2^log_2 N)] / 0.5 =
     2^log_2 N = N
     = (N - 1) / 0.5
```

So `T(N)` is `O(N)`.

Comment: @IVIad, I understood how you calculated T(n) = O(n). But I think this you have calculated for the outer for loop only. But what should we do for the inner for loop?

Comment: @DG4 no, it's for the whole program. When `i = N`, the inner gets executed `N` times. When `i = N/2`, the inner gets executed `N/2` times, and so on. So the sum takes everything into account.

Answer (score -1):

the answer to  this question is O(N^2)

Comment: Since Big O notation is an upper bound, your answer is technically correct. However, the goal of the question is to justify the tightest, or smallest, bound possible. O(n^2) is larger than questioner's O(n*log n), and another answerer has provided justification for a smaller, tighter O(n) through a geometric series.